# How to ignore the CSS style from the parent box?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, css, razor

I'm trying to put some code of a complete Html page where I've setted inside of a frame. I feel obligated to use put all of this content in a box because the innet text has its own page and its own style.

I'm looking for the way to not to inherit the style from the LayoutPage. I can't reference the page because I need to use the Razor to set some values through the model.

What can I do to override all the styles inside of the frame?

```
@model Contoso.Core.Exercises.TimesTables.Exercise1

<frame>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<!-- Generated by WebWorksheet version 3.5.1 on 31/05/2013 www.webworksheet.com -->
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>Times Tables</title>
<script type='text/javascript'>
   var wwsRelease = 'http://webworksheet.com/release/030501';
   var iterations = 3;
   var imageFolder = 'wwsImages';
   var displayZeroes = true;
   var dbConnection = '';
   var dbQueryScript = '';
   var firstInput = 'iB54';
   var datePickerAuto = '';
   var datePickerImg = '';
   var activeBorder = '2px solid black';
   var activeBackground = 'transparent';
   var lastBtnClick = '';
   var protectPage = false;
   var webQueries = new Array();
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://webworksheet.com/release/030501/webworksheet.js'></script>

<style type='text/css'>
@@media all {
 Body {overflow:auto;}
 A {text-decoration:none; cursor:pointer; color:inherit;}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946645/how-to-ignore-parent-css-style

Comment: But I have a super large CSS Style in the parent.. I should have to override many attributes :/

Comment: It could be me, but: `<frame>`?! Are you sure about this?

Answer (score 2):

Give different styles for the child element for the same css property. Like

> .parent {
>
> ```
>      background-color: green;
> ```
>
> }
>
> .parent .child{
>
> ```
>      background-color: red;
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `!important;` keyword.for example:

```
text-decoration:none!important;
```

Comment: But I'm talking about several CSS and many attributes in it. There's no way to ignore all the style from the parent?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002997/override-css-style-of-parent-element-without-affecting-other-elements

Answer (score 0):

If you are using class to give css to that particular tag then you can simply set class name as blank or another class whatever you want to use:

```
document.getElementById("tagid").className = "";
```

OR

```
document.getElementById("tagid").className = "class2";
```

And If you are able to use `JQuery` then it is very simple to remove parent class like this:

```
<script>$("tagid").removeClass("oldclass");</script>
```

for more details for JQuery [click here](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

Answer (score 0):

For me, I couldn't get the class .userLink to be recognized.  Then I realized it was under a DIV with id=#nav3, which in the CSS already had a style defined for **#div3 a**.  From Jazmin's answer above, I tried this and it got the class to work again.

```
#nav3 .userLink 
{
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: blue;
}
```